# RealmSwift: listing all active notification tokens

Tags: swift, notifications, realm

Is there a way in Realm (RealmSwift) to list all the active [notificationTokens](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications)?

Comment: Whilst, I'm not sure on a concrete answer. I do believe this isn't possible and for good reason. Notification tokes can/should invalidate themselves if the view is deallocated or stopped manually. So the only half reliable method is checking the token for that VC - if needed.

Comment: You should know what active notification tokens were created as you created them. In general they would be a class level var as a strong reference is needed to keep it alive. See [Notifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/notifications#realm-notifications) note the `deinit` function with `token.invalidate()`. If you have several, you could add them to an array. We could probably formulate an answer if we understood the use case - what is the situation where you would need to know that information?

Comment: Clear, I get the idea one should be manually collecting notification tokens and keep track of them, thank you.

My bigger issue is that I am trying to figure out the reason my app goes into a deluge of DeepChangeChecker-related computations and becomes non-responsive for a number of seconds.

At this point I understand the problem is either related to the architecture of the notifications or the schema and this question was a step in figuring it out.

I guess I will either post a new, complete question or start an issue in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.

Comment: BTW, there is an error in the "Object Notifications" section of https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/notifications#object-notifications docs. The Swift example used is that of the "Collection Notifications". I open an issue about it in the Docs Github repository.

Comment: Here is the issue I opened based on this: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/7072

Comment: Ok. Understood and thank you for reporting the documentation error. The issue here is that additional troubleshooting is needed to determine where the error actually is, and the question should include the troublesome code along with where things are going wrong within that code. So for example *my app goes into a deluge of DeepChangeChecker-related computations* - what does that mean? On what line of code does that occur? If you remove notifications does it still happen? What if you perform a split half search to eliminate some of the notifications? Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: I will add the GitHub issue is very well done and documented and I can understand why the question was posed as it is. However, this question is not going to be answerable as-is on this site because it doesn't include the code in question, which is pretty much a requirement here on SO.

Comment: Thank for all of your comments, Jay. What's better: should I start a new  question here on SO or does it belong to the GitHub issue I created more? The question as I formulated here, seems to be answered in the sense, there is no convenience functions to list all the active notification tokens.